# How can I associate a SO account with an older SE account?

Tags: support, openid, stack-exchange, association

I currently have an account on an "older" StackExchange site:

http://epicadvice.com/users/252

However, that account is not automatically associated with my SO profile in any way, and I don't seem to be able to find any button to add associations.

The OpenID and email address that I have used on EA is the same as what I use on SO.

Is there anyway to associate these two accounts, manually or otherwise? Am I missing something obvious with regard to association? (Other search results for meta.so seem to be for things like 'careers', which aren't of the older StackExchange variety.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.  They are `by-design` two separate systems, just as each SE1.0 site is a separate system.

Comment: Okay. Thanks for the help. (I'd upvote your answer, but apparently I don't have enough rep. :p)